# Login failed during python Insert job with BigQuery API

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I am trying load local file to bigquery by setting up a server-server auth.
I've done following steps

1. Created service account
2. Create JSON key file for this account
3. Activated service acount with

   gcloud auth activate-service-account command
4. Logged in with

   gcloud auth login
5. Trying to execute python script to upload file to BigQuery

   scopes =

   ```
   ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.insertdata']

   credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
       '/path/privatekey.json', scopes)
   # Construct the service object for interacting with the BigQuery API.
   service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

   # Load configuration with the destination specified.
   load_config = {
       'destinationTable': {
           'projectId': "project id",
           'datasetId': "data set id",
           'tableId': "table name"
       }
   }

   # Setup the job here.
   # load[property] = value
   load_config['schema'] = {
       'fields': [
           <several field>
       ]
   }


   upload = MediaFileUpload('/path/to/csv/file',
                            mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                            # This enables resumable uploads.
                            resumable=True)
   # End of job configuration.

   run_load.start_and_wait(service.jobs(),
                           "my project id",
                           load_config,
                           media_body=upload)
   ```
6. The result is

   ```
      "error": {
       "errors": [
      {
       "domain": "global",
       "reason": "required",
       "message": "Login Required",
       "locationType": "header",
       "location": "Authorization"
      }
     ],
     "code": 401,
     "message": "Login Required"
    }
   }
   ```
7. But I have enough rights to create query jobs

   ```
   query_request = service.jobs()
   query_data = {
       'query': (
           'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dmrebg.testDay];')
   }

   query_response = query_request.query(
       projectId=project_id,
       body=query_data).execute()

   print('Query Results:')
   for row in query_response['rows']:
       print('\t'.join(field['v'] for field in row['f']))
   ```

---

What did I miss? I thought that I've already logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that any call to 
https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project_id/jobs/* will cause the same problem

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

So it is a problem with my browser auth, python auth is good.

---

And root cause is that I my CSV Schema and data do not match.

```
Errors:
Too many errors encountered. (error code: invalid)
```